# Method call to bool values not working

Tags: c#, methods, boolean

I have a working piece of code which, when it comes across an error within a text file being read in, it colors that text to highlight it, as it's written back out to a new file.

```
    if (item.LogEntry.ToUpper().Contains("Error=\"Device Not Found\"".ToUpper()))
    {
       //Write out to new file in red to highlight error
    }
    else
    {
      //Write out to new file as normal
    }
```

I am trying to write all this in a method named **GetCriticalErrors()**. I am using a bool to return a true or false on finding an error. This is what I have so far.

```
    bool aCriticalError;
    public bool GetCriticalErrors(string logEntry)
    {
        foreach (var item in logEntry.ToUpper())
        {
            if (item.ToString().Contains("Error=\"Device Not Found\"".ToUpper()))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return aCriticalError;
    }
```

I am calling the method like so

```
    if (GetCriticalErrors(item.LogEntry) == true)
    {
       //Write out to new file in red to highlight error
    }
    else
    {
        //Write out to new file as normal
    }
```

The problem is that this way of using a method is not working. I'm not sure why? It's not throwing up any errors. It's just not coloring the error text in the newly written file. The original code worked but I need to put it into a method, passing in the item.LogEntry. Can anyone see where I have gone wrong with it?

Also, to answer something that was pointed out, I will be searching for many different error messages over many strings. It's not just this one error and it may appear many times.

Comment: Could people down voting please explain the reason for the down vote? If there is something wrong with the question just let me know.

Answer (score 5):

Here's your problem:-

```
foreach (var item in logEntry.ToUpper())
```

`logEntry` is a `string` not a collection of strings! You're iterating over a string character by character, so `item` is of type `char` and `item.ToString().Contains("Error=\"Device Not Found\"".ToUpper())` won't ever be true.

If you're only checking one string, use:-

```
private readonly string errorString = "Error=\"Device Not Found\"".ToUpper();

public bool GetCriticalErrors(string logEntry)
{
  return logEntry.ToUpper().Contains(errorString);
}
```

If you're checking multiple strings:-

```
public bool GetCriticalErrors(IEnumerable<string> logEntries)
{
  return logEntries.Any(x => x.ToUpper().Contains(errorString));
}
```

If you're checking one string for multiple errors:-

```
private IEnumerable<string> errorStrings = new[]
{
  "Error=\"Device Not Found\"".ToUpper(),
  ...
};

public bool GetCriticalErrors(string logEntry)
{
  var logEntryUpper = logEntry.ToUpper();
  return errorStrings.Any(x => logEntry.Contains(x));
}
```

As an aside, `.ToUpper()` isn't really a very good way of doing a case-insensitive compare. You might want to consider instead something along the lines of:-

```
return logEntry.IndexOf("Error=\"Device Not Found\"",
                        StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1;
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you @Iain but I will be searching through many strings.

Comment: Then you'll need to pass a collection of strings into your method, or call your method from inside the foreach!

Comment: Also, don't use `ToUpper` for comparison - just use `logEntry.Contains(searchString, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)`.

Comment: @Luaan: Sadly `string.Contains` doesn't have an overload that takes a `StringComparer`. No idea why. You have to use `string.IndexOf` instead (or presumably one of the many utility methods in `culture.CompareInfo`)

Answer (score 2):

`logEntry` is a string so no need to use `for-each` and you also need to use `.ToUpper()` on both input string and string to check

```
public bool GetCriticalErrors(string logEntry)
{       
    return logEntry.ToUpper().Contains("Error=\"Device Not Found\"".ToUpper());
}

//If you want to check in list of string
public bool GetCriticalErrors(List<string> logEntries)
{       
    var errorStr = "Error=\"Device Not Found\"".ToUpper();
    return logEntries.Any(l => l.ToUpper().Contains(errorStr));
}
```